# Can you use a npm package without using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I found a library on github that I would like to use but the download instructions only mention using npm but I am not using a NodeJS project (just a basic html,css,javascript front-end with no back-end server). Am I still able to use that library or is it a lost cause? Is there another way to download it without using npm?

Comment: Which library is it?

Comment: https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx

Answer (score 5):

> Is there another way to download it without using npm?

If it's on github, then you can checkout or fork the repository as you can with any other git repo.

> Am I still able to use that library or is it a lost cause?

Whether or not the library will work without Node will depend on the library.

If it presents itself as a Node module, then you'll probably have to modify it (or find a compatible *module loader* for browser-side JS).

If it depends on NodeJS features (such as the filesystem API) then you'll be out of luck (unless, for example, you polyfill them to work across HTTP)

Answer (score 3):

If you use a build tool such as [browserify](http://browserify.org/), or [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/), you can author scripts that `require` node modules and the build tool will generate a script that includes all the necessary dependencies (assuming that the necessary dependencies are compatible with client-side JavaScript environments).

Downloading dependencies would still be done via `npm`, but only for local development. Your server would only need the generated script.

Alternatively, if the script is on github or any other repo online you may be able to download it directly. Many modules are published using [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd), which would allow you to use the script using various inclusion methods.